# How to hide the "trimmed version" from the preview page?

Tags: 7, forms

When I "preview" a node add/edit form it shows a "trimmed version" and a "full version". I don't want to show the trimmed version.

The [fix](http://drupal.org/node/1005234) suggested for D6 doesn't work for D7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tried CSS?

```
.preview h3 , .preview .node.node-article.node-teaser {display: none}
```

In my case the content type is an article and worked.

Comment: looks like I will also hide this status message: The trimmed version of your post shows what your post looks like when promoted to the main page or when exported for syndication. You can insert the delimiter "<!--break-->" (without the quotes) to fine-tune where your post gets split.

Comment: Thx for the help this worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can also override this page by using drupal 7's templating system.

Go to your modules/node/node.pages.inc file and find this function. It's line 422 for me.

```
function theme_node_preview($variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  $output = '<div class="preview">';

  $preview_trimmed_version = FALSE;

  $elements = node_view(clone $node, 'teaser');
  $trimmed = drupal_render($elements);
  $elements = node_view($node, 'full');
  $full = drupal_render($elements);

  // Do we need to preview trimmed version of post as well as full version?
  if ($trimmed != $full) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The trimmed version of your post shows what your post looks like when promoted to the main page or when exported for syndication.<span class="no-js"> You can insert the delimiter "&lt;!--break--&gt;" (without the quotes) to fine-tune where your post gets split.</span>'));
    $output .= '<h3>' . t('Preview trimmed version') . '</h3>';
    $output .= $trimmed;
    $output .= '<h3>' . t('Preview full version') . '</h3>';
    $output .= $full;
  }
  else {
    $output .= $full;
  }
  $output .= "</div>\n";

  return $output;
}
```

Then go to your template.php file of your theme and rename and modify the function to something like this:

```
function your_theme_node_preview($variables){
  $node = $variables['node'];

  $output = '<div class="preview">';

  $preview_trimmed_version = FALSE;

  $elements = node_view($node, 'full');
  $full = drupal_render($elements);

  // Do we need to preview trimmed version of post as well as full version?
  $output .= '<p>You may make further edits below or click save when finished.</p><hr/>';

  $output .= $full;

  $output .= "</div>\n";

  return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

1. go to admin/structure/types/manage/ on your site,
2. Select manage display fields for your desire content type ,
3. go to the teaser tab - set it to hidden at the format and save
   .

   next time when you edit the content just close the summary by click on the link (Hide summary)

Comment: I removed the "teaser" tab from display but I don't see a "hide summary" link when editing content.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the CSS that worked for me was the following one.

```
.preview h3 , .preview article.node-teaser {display: none;}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is really going to depend on your site theme.  This answer assumes an HTML5 theme.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this also:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#console").hide();
  $(".preview h3").hide();
  $(".preview .node-teaser").hide();
});
```